Linguistic criticism and censorship (Il criticismo linguistico e la censura)
Come mai la mia risposta alla domanda «“Uno dei più grandi fisici” o “una delle più grandi fisiche”, detto di una donna?» è stata cancellata? E perché?
È che il criticismo sull'evoluzione socioculturale dell'italiano è sgradito o è vera e propria censura?
E, se l'ultima, chi è il censore?
Qui c'è il testo della risposta.

How come my answer to the question «“Uno dei più grandi fisici” o “una delle più grandi fisiche”, detto di una donna?» («“One [masculine] of the greatest physicists [masculine]” or “one [feminine] of the greatest physicists [feminine]”, referring to a woman?») was deleted? And why?
Is it that criticism regarding the sociocultural evolution of Italian is unwelcome or is it pure censorship?
And, if it is the latter, who is the censor?
Here you find the text of the answer.


Can this meta question be translated into English and reposted for users who may not speak Italian?

@anahevesi Done! ILU is the site where everything is possibile. Great thanks to randomatlabuser.

Thanks! Though I couldn't find the link...would you drop a link to the translated version into the question above?

@AnaH I'm working to translate that answer, but I need some days yet.

Understood. :) I made a related meta post -- if it gets to be hard to translate, you may want to instate an English-only meta policy.

I'm not the censor and, on a personal level, I would not have deleted it, but the site is not intended for to collect users' opinions, even less so when they are of political nature.
The purpose of the site is to collect comprehensive answers, with sources which are traceable, neutral and not personal opinions on the language and its evolution. The idea is to build a qualitative resource that gathers questions and answers to linguistic issues of the Italian language, not simply being a rehash of things already easily found on the web, but integrating them with with off-web sources and the users' own personal expertise.

Non sono il censore e non l'avrei cancellata, personalmente. Ma il sito non è inteso per dare opinioni, men che mai di natura politica.
Lo scopo è fornire risposte articolate e con fonti rintracciabili, neutre e prive di ogni visione personale sulla lingua e la sua evoluzione. Si tratta di costruire una risorsa di qualità che raccolga domande e risposte a questioni linguistiche sull'italiano, che non sia una riproposizione di cose già reperibili sul web ma le integri, assieme a fonti non web-rintracciabili e alla competenza degli utenti stessi,

According to the StackExchange rules, an answer that does not contain an original idea and just repeats another answer, can be deleted. If you want to say that you agree with randomatlabuser's answer, you could always add a comment.
Moreover, those answers and comments, which go well beyond the purpose of the question and are flagged as "non-constructive/off-topic", also should be deleted, as you may read  here.

Secondo le regole di StackExchange, la risposta, che non rappresenta un'idea originale e soltanto ripete un'altra risposta, può essere cancellata. Se vuoi dire che sei d'accordo con la risposta di randomatlabuser, potresti sempre lasciare un commento.
Inoltre, debbono essere cancellati anche quelli risposte e commenti fuori dallo scopo della domanda, che vengono segnalati come "not constructive / off-topic", come puoi leggere qua.

Io sono tra coloro che avevano votato perché venisse cancellata. A parte le motivazioni che spiega I.M. (è al massimo un commento, non una vera risposta): pensi veramente che in un sito sulla linguistica siano utili risposte che parlano di “stupidaggini” e “scompisciarsi”?
Irridere un fenomeno linguistico sarebbe come irridere la forza di gravità o l'esistenza delle pulsar. Studia questi argomenti, ignorali, chiedi informazioni, danne: ma dire che il teorema di Pitagora ti fa “scompisciare” farebbe scompisciare, no?

DaG, per piacere, non provocare un'altra discussione sulle forze della natura, ignoranza, opinioni personali, ecc. C'è un chat, ci sono moltissimi forum... Non qui.

@I.M., dato che siamo su meta la mia risposta aveva senso così com'era, per spiegare che in un sito su una lingua si parla di fatti linguistici. Una forma dialettale di congiuntivo, per dire, è come una specie vegetale: va studiata, non irrisa (né esaltata). Ti prego di ripristinare la mia risposta o, se proprio credi, di cancellarla del tutto.

@DaG I 'fatti linguistici', in specie per ciò che attiene all'evoluzione della lingua, non possono essere separati dalle questioni socioculturali, né è possibile negare che l'ideologia femminista, in Italia sponsorizzata dagli intellettuali di sinistra, abbia determinato certe storpiature come 'ministra', 'ingegnera' e 'sindaca'.

@ElberichSchneider: Le relazioni strette fra fratti linguistici (perché le virgolette?) ed eventi sociopolitici sono verissime, e sarebbe bene approfondirle anche qui (io stesso proposi una tag “sociolinguistics”): il fatto è che in questa sede vanno trattate in modo neutro, non parlandone in termini di “stupidaggini” e “storpiature”.
